# How to search file in folder by using php?

Tags: php, glob, scandir, readdir, opendir

I have a folder called `allfiles`, and there are some files in this folder, such as

```
 1212-how-to-sddk-thosd.html
 3454-go-to-dlkkl-sdf.html
 0987-sfda-asf-fdf-12331.html
 4789-how-to-fdaaf-65536.html
```

I use `scandir` to list all files, and now I need to find the file by with keywords, example `to-dlkkl` is the keyword, and I will get the file `3454-go-to-dlkkl-sdf.html`.

Glob seems not work, and opendir and readdir are not work well, any ideas?

Comment: What did you try for `glob`? I'm thinking that you'll need something like this: `glob("/path/to/allfiles/*to-dlkkl*")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use loop `foreach` and `strpos` function:

```
$files = scandir('allfiles');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (strpos('to-dlkkl', $file) !== false) {
         //file found
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You are wellcome

Comment: strpos is haystack needle, not needle haystack

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why glob() function not working for it?

The below code should work I guess,

```
$existing_dir = getcwd();
// path to dir
chdir( '/var/www/allfiles/' );

foreach( glob( '*to-dlkkl*.html' ) as $html_file ) {
    echo $html_file . '<br />';
}

chdir( $existing_dir );
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use strstr to get actual file

```
$allfiles = scandir('./');
foreach ($allfiles as $file) {
    if (strstr($file, 'to-dlkkl')) {
        echo "file found"; //do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to search specific file under directory then you can use `preg_match()` .

```
<?php
  if ($handle = opendir('/var/www/html/j')) { // here add your directory
  $keyword = "index.php"; // your keyword
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        // (preg_match('/\.txt$/', $entry)) {
        if (preg_match('/'.$keyword.'/i', $entry)) {
            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}

?>
```